# How to read data from serial port using C#

Tags: windows, windows-10, serial-port

I have to create as I thought pretty simple thing. I have physical button and serial port which is in my motherboard. I want to write a program which reads if button is pressed and that is it. The issue is I don't see any COM port in device manager (I use windows 10). Also I read I could receive some data from serial port if I connect 1 and 7 pin together.

Why I couldn't see COM Port and is it possible to make it work like is wrote above?

Answer (score 2):

1. > "Why I couldn't see COM Port"

- **Solution 1**: Sometimes it's just **hidden**. You need to open **Device Manager** -> select **View** tab -> choose **Show hidden devices**. You might be able to see the **Ports (COM & LPT)** option.
- **Solution 2**: Update your motherboard drivers.
- **Solution 3**: Manually add your COM Ports. Check out this [link](https://windowsreport.com/device-manager-add-com-port/).

2. > "How to read data from serial port"

```
public static void Main()
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

    mySerialPort.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
    mySerialPort.Close();
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

Everytime data comes in, the DataReceivedHandler will trigger and prints your data to the console.

You can check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners) out for reference.